# Remove directory name from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Because all my files are php I have removed php extension with this .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

So I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/live/kanal/some-title-1
http://example.com/live/kanal/some-title-2
http://example.com/live/kanal/some-title-13
http://example.com/live/kanal/some-title-45
http://example.com/live/kanal/2some-title-333
```

etc ...

I want to hide kanal/ from url, to get URL like this:

```
http://example.com/live/some-title-1
http://example.com/live/some-title-2
http://example.com/live/some-title-13
http://example.com/live/some-title-45
http://example.com/live/2some-title-333
```

How can I achieve this using mod_rewrite?

I used online generators for doing the rewrite rules but none can remove a piece of text from the URL. Also I made search on this forum, and I found some posts about mod rewrite directory but I have issues when pasting in my .htacess code.

Comment: In root I have one .htacess. In this file I have only 404 redirection.
In http://example.com/live/ I have another, this is .htacess from beginning of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in **`/live/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /live/

RewriteRule ^(?!kanal/)(.*)$ kanal/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure there is no .htaccess in `kanal/` sub-directory.

Comment: Very strange. I get this:
Index of /live/kanal
and all my files in this directory are listed..

Comment: My old .htacess, where I just remove .php extension you can view on th post beginning. Now I use your code and replace my old .htacess in live folder. After that I called url http://example.com/live/ and get all files list in kanal/ folder.

Comment: That's correct behavior then because it could hide `kanal` folder. What happens when you enter `http://example.com/live/some-title-1` URL?

Comment: Yeah channel http://example.com/live/some-title-1 works! But only index of is a problem.

Comment: What happens when you directly enter `http://example.com/live/kanal/` URL in browser? Please be little quick to respond.

Comment: Yes works finaly! :) I was moved index from live to live/kanal/ and changed a link patch. All is working. Thanks!